# Why is SSRS ignoring data from certain columns returned by a web method?

Tags: sql-server, web-services, soap, reporting-services

I'm using the XML data source feature in Reporting Services 2005 but having some issues with missing data. When there is no value for the first column in a row, it appears that the entire column is ignored by SSRS!

The web method request is very simple:

```
<Query>
   <Method Name="GetIssues" 
Namespace="http://www.mycompany.com/App/">
   </Method>
   <SoapAction>http://www.mycompany.com/App/GetIssues</SoapAction>
   <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">*</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

Equally, the response is very simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetIssuesResponse xmlns="http://www.mycompany.com/App/">
      <GetIssuesResult>
        <Issue>
          <Title>ABC</Title>
          <RaisedBy />
          <Action>Do something</Action>
        </Issue>
        <Issue>
          <Title>ABC</Title>
          <RaisedBy>Jeff Smith</RaisedBy>
          <Action>Do something</Action>
        </Issue>
      </GetIssuesResult>
    </GetIssuesResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

In this example the RaisedBy column will be completely empty. If the 'Issues' are reversed so RaisedBy first has a value, there is no problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Any chance you could post your RDL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Query itself, try to define your columns explicitly, instead of letting SSRS determine them for you.

In other words, where you have:

```
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">*</ElementPath>
```

Replace the * with something like:

```
<ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">GetIssues/GetIssuesItemsResult/listitems/data/row{@Title,@RaisedBy,@Action}</ElementPath>
```

Of course, that exact XPath may not be correct for your example.

Comment: Thank you! The correct XPath was: GetIssuesResponse/GetIssuesResult/Issue{Title,RaisedBy,Action}

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to eliminate the NULLs in the XML? Replace them with an empty string? Then you won't have to wrestle with SSRS.

If the XML is generated from a database call, that's easy enough to do (ISNULL in SQL Server).